# How to run coverage installed in local/user inside a venv

Tags: python, code-coverage

Hi I want to run coverage in my virtual environment. coverage is installed in the local/global/user directory.

The reason is that I need my venv to have highly controlled dependencies, each one analysed and approved by SecOps, and coverage bring and could bring in the future a lot of unknown and uncontrolled dependencies.

And thus coverage is only necessary for development purposes I don't see the point why should be part of my requirements.txt

Is there a way to handle this in a way that coverage is installed in my local/global/user dependencies (sorry I'm new to the python ecosystem just extrapolating other ecosystems to this one) but it won't propagate to my server side (which is populated by a CI that install whatever is in requirements.txt).

**The whole thing uses pip and no other dependency manager will or could be used.**

The error I'm receiving is that coverage cannot find the dependencies installed in my venv, even if I run the coverage from the activated venv.

These are the methods I've tried so far, nothing seems to work

### Forcing PYTHONPATH

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
coverage run --omit=$omit_paths -m unittest discover
coverage html --omit=$omit_paths
```

### Forcing sys.path

running coverage pointing to a bootstrap file that makes the discover and forces sys.path to be as it is when running unittest alone which works just fine

./test/**init**.py

```py
...
sys.path = [# EXPORT of sys.path existing when running unittest only]
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the specific error you get?

Comment: It's unable to find a 3rd party module that is installed in the venv, the typical module not found error of python.
Sorry for the secrecy but cannot show that log :(

Comment: FWIW, by default, coverage has no dependencies. If you use "pip install coverage", it won't install anything but coverage.